# serial stops between mbed and processing

Tags: processing, serial-communication, mbed

I want a solution right now...

The LPC1768 which is one of a mbed prototyping boards communicates with processing through Serial whose baud rate is 115200. However, as time passes, the serial communication stops.

As a situation, the LPC1768 sends sensor data with serial.putc() of the default serial library. On the other hand, processing receives the data with serial.read(). The processing code is the following:

```
if(serial.available()>1) { serial.read(); }
```

To explore the solution of this problem, I tired these things.

- I checked serial.available() is 46 and used serial.clear() in processing, but mbed stopped and didn't send data. Because I thought the cause of this was an overflow of receiving buffer of processing.
- I added serial.writable() and check the serial buffers for sending has space. If there are no space, I used the following codes and initialized the serial:

  ```
  LPC_UART2->FCR |= 0x06; 
  serial.baud(115200);
  ```

, because I thought the cause of this was an overflow of sending buffer of mbed. However, they didn't work.

Please note that these codes work correctly and basically.
However, serial communication stops suddenly. What can I do anything else?

Best regards

Comment: I've never used an LPC1768 before so take my tips with a pinch of salt. Check if there's a flush() like function on the LPC1768 serial communication side to clear the communication buffer and try Serial's [clear()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_clear_.html) on the Processing side. Additionally try to build a timeout system on processing: have a millis counter since the last received packet and if that counter goes above a threshold value, close the serial port and re-initialize it and reset the counter.

Comment: Hi, George.

Thank you for your quick reply. I think the second try has the same function as flush on the LPC1768. Additionally, on Processing, Serial's clear() didn't work. So, as you propose, I implemented a timeout system on processing and this problem was solved apparently. Thank you for your advise. 

However, I want to know the intrinsic solution. I found the following thread about arduino: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=77828.0 , but  any solutions are not found.

Comment: Hi. I agree: a clean solution based the actual cause of the problem would be great. If you have the time, it's probably worth investigating, otherwise, from a pragmatic point of view simply identifying communication drops and re-starting comms should do. On the receiving end I'd try to log the times when the connection drops and see if there's a pattern: does it always drop after about the same amount of time ? On the electronics side, would it be possible to sample voltage/current over time and see if there's a drop after a while that might affect RX/TX lines ?